# Applying the DRY principle in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, zurb-foundation

Trying to do some clean programming in Google Apps Script.  Does anyone know how to reuse oft-repeated method/property chains?  Example:

```
var lblDate = app.createLabel("Date")
    .setId('lblDate')
    .setStyleAttribute("fontFamily", "\"Helvetica Neue\", \"HelveticaNeue\", Helvetica,   Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif")
    .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "14px")
    .setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "1.4rem")
    .setStyleAttribute("lineHeight", "1")
    .setStyleAttribute("color", "#222222")
    .setStyleAttribute("position", "relative");
```

This question has many implications for me, but the task at hand (above) is applying Zurb Foundation styles across various form elements using only GAS Javascript.

Any takers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you do something like:

```
function applyCSS(element, style) {
  for (var key in style) {
    element.setStyleAttribute(key, style[key]);
  }
}

var _zurb1 = 
  {
    "fontFamily": "\"Helvetica Neue\", \"HelveticaNeue\", Helvetica,   Arial, \"Lucida Grande\", sans-serif",
    "fontSize": "14px",
    "fontSize": "1.4rem",
    "lineHeight": "1",
    "color": "#222222",
    "position": "relative"
  }
```

And then in your main code:

```
var lblDate = app.createLabel("Date").setId('lblDate');
applyCSS(lblDate, _zurb1);
```

All credit for this method to James Ferreira, author of Google Script (Enterprise Application Essentials).

---

*edit (4/09/2012)*

With the new [setStyleAttributes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_label#setStyleAttributes) method I think you can now do away with the applyCSS() function and just use:

```
var lblDate = app.createLabel("Date").setId('lblDate').setStyleAttributes(_zurb1);
```

Comment: Just a warning.  Internet Explorer does not like the two different assignments of fontSize.  If I was smarter I could tell you why, but it throws an error.  I simply eliminated the second and ran it fine on Chrome, Mozilla and Explorer.

Comment: @MartinK Good web designers shouldn't care about IE specific quirks. Simply inform the users with a panel on top of the webpage to use better standards compliant browsers.