# Google Apps Script Gadget not displaying properly in web browsers

Tags: google-apps-script, internet-explorer-8, google-sites

On my www.OnSiteBAC.com/ViewMyBlows google site I've inserted an Apps Script Gadget (by pasting the URL of an Apps Script that I published as a service). This apps script gadget allows the user to enter a value (their 'Blow Number') and view the corresponding data (based on API calls to my Google Fusion tables).

The problem is that this apps script gadget does not load as expected.  It does not load at all in IE8 and loads with a 'This application was created by another user, not by Google' message in Chrome and FireFox.  I want the application to load as part of the web page (with no messages or errors).

Please advise...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Google message will appear no matter, as long as the user hasn't disabled this message in the past.  It is not what I would like to see either, but it's the policy.

As to the not displaying in IE8.  Couple things, Google doesn't like IE, and especially not older versions.  As Google is fond of saying "GAS works in any modern browser." And, they don't count IE as one of those.

But as you haven't provided any code...

I'm going to take the guess that it could be due to your styling.   I'd used the answer offered in [Applying the DRY principle in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679448/applying-the-dry-principle-in-google-apps-script)

It failed in IE as well, and here was my fix

> Just a warning. Internet Explorer does not like the two different
>   assignments of fontSize. If I was smarter I could tell you why, but it
>   throws an error. I simply eliminated the second and ran it fine on
>   Chrome, Mozilla and Explorer.

Comment: Hi Martin- thanks for the response- will the google warning message go away if I purchase a 'Google Apps For Business' account?  As you can see in posts 15 and 35, it looks like Google removes the message if you subscribe: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=522.  I was hoping to avoid the annual fee, but may need to if there are no other options :(

Comment: Yeah, it will go away with a pay account.  I just checked my Google Apps for Nonprofits, and no warning shows. Should be the same with the Business account.   I should have realized that the accounts were functioning differently in regard to the error message.  Thanks for finding the issue.